# javascript function not working properly. (target)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function hide(target) {
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
var ID = document.getElementById(target).value;
```

For some reason, the display = 'none' part is working perfect, how ever when i pass 'ID' (var ID) via ajax - it just says Undefined.

Any ideas how to get Var ID to be the same as (target) the ID of the div tag?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the relevant piece of ajax code?

Comment: what is target? if it says undefined, it may mean that it has no value at all or is an element that doesn't have any value property (like a div or a span). can you please provide us the HTML and where you are using the function?

Comment: You've marked this as jquery - but not used jquery.  Please update the tags if you're not using jquery.  Are you using jquery for the ajax call?

Comment: Without seeing your 'pass via ajax' code, it's not possible to tell what the problem is (most likely a `closure` issue).  Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with emphasis on *complete*.

Comment: you mean `var ID = target`?

Comment: Probably you are not waiting to the ajax response or you are working outside the ajax scope, so your variable is undefined because it has no value yet

Comment: @jamie Do you really want to access the value attribute of the div or you want to access a value(like a textbox's) inside the div ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the routine to use a more defensive technique:

```
    function hide(target) {
        if ( typeof target != "string") {
            return;
        }
        var el = document.getElementById(target);

        if ( typeof el == "object" ) {
            el.style.display = 'none';

            var ID = el.value;

            // do something with ID
        }
    }
```